# Use HttpsURLConnection to make HTTP and HTTPS request's

Tags: java, api

There is a way to use HttpsURLConnection to do HTTP and HTTPS request ?

I am using just a method to do API request's but in localhost I'm not using https, so I want to use a HttpsURLConnection to do https and http request's without check protocol to create HttpsURLConnection or HttpURLConnection

Thanks!
Sorry by my english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I solved with something like emandt suggest

```
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
HttpsURLConnection httpsConn = null;
HttpURLConnection httpConn = null;
boolean isOverHttps = conn instanceof HttpsURLConnection;

if (isOverHttps) {
    httpsConn = (HttpsURLConnection) conn;
    httpsConn.setSSLSocketFactory(sslcontext.getSocketFactory());
}else{
    httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
}
```

And to set params and get response

```
(isOverHttps ? httpsConn : httpConn).setRequestProperty("Content-Type", service.getConTypeService());

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((isOverHttps ? httpsConn : httpConn).getInputStream(), "utf-8"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the problem.

URL can be HTTP or HTTPS without change any piece of code:

```
URL cUrl = new URL("http://www.google.com");
//cUrl = new URL("https://www.google.com");   //<-- decomment this line to use an HTTPS
final URLConnection cURLConnection = cUrl.openConnection();
cURLConnection.connect();
if (cURLConnection instanceof HttpURLConnection) ...when url=http://...
else if (cURLConnection instanceof HttpsURLConnection) ...when url=https://...
else ...
```

HttpsURLConnection extends HttpURLConnection, so you can consider to have always an "HttpURLConnection" object except if/when you need to use specific HttpsURLConnection methods, than you can check the instance using "instanceof".

Comment: When the Request is over https I set setSSLSocketFactory manually, and the URLConnection does not permit

Comment: Then you can use "instanceof" to detect when the request is over HTTPS as I showed you...